# auto foo = ref new Foo(); What is "ref"?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I was watching a video from, //build/ and several of the MS developers were using a syntax like this in their C++11 programs:

```
auto foo = ref new Foo();
```

I understand what everything does in this line except "ref". What does that mean?

Comment: Just so nobody gets the wrong idea: This is not C++11 syntax! It's a Microsoft extension.

Comment: You should check this video "Using the Windows Runtime from C++" http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-532T at 14:30

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The forthcoming Visual C++ compiler adds this syntax for dealing with WinRT objects (which are in turn the next generation of COM, what have we gone through now?  COM, DCOM, COM+, ActiveX, ...)

That line is nearly equivalent to:

```
com_ptr_t<Foo> foo = CreateInstance<Foo>();
```

But there's a new version of `com_ptr_t` as well, using the syntax `Foo^`.

Comment: That strikes me as a somewhat radical syntax abuse. I don't know WinRT, but does this create a dynamic instance on the C++ (native) heap?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Pretty sure it uses an OS allocator, like COM objects have traditionally done (but like everything else, I'm sure there's a new and improved WinRT allocator instead of [the good-ol' COM allocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693395(v=vs.85).aspx)).  So it's a dynamic instance on a heap, but not the heap managed by the C++ runtime and used for `new` and `delete`.

Comment: When such a reference goes out of scope, is the object released?

Comment: @JörgenSigvardsson: There's automatic reference counting, sort of like `boost::shared_ptr`.  `com_ptr_t` already did that as well.  Why they introduced a special syntax for something built into C++ I don't know.

Comment: @Ben IIRC, the allocator for objects (just as with vanilla COM) is technically a class factory implementation detail, and doesn't even need to be on the heap - so long as object's lifetime is properly corresponding to `AddRef` / `Release`.

Comment: @Ben I don't claim to know the specific reasons for this design decision, but one thing that immediately comes to mind from several years of writing C++ & COM code in ATL is that smart pointers implemented as template classes don't play well with an API that does not use them - you end up having to explicitly wrap/unwrap raw pointers into smart ones at the API boundary. A particularly nasty case is when pointer is an out parameter - so you end up having to provide a raw pointer variable for that before wrapping it - or else overload unary `&` like ATL does and break STL.

Comment: @PavelMinaev: Overloaded `operator&` is no longer a violation of STL constraints. Secondly, APIs *designed* to be written with the new stuff could just take a `com_ptr_t`. However, Herb Sutter said that they very nearly did make it library-only in C++, but there were some strange edge cases which produced very bad performance as a library and they had to make it language to solve them. The syntax enhancements themselves were already in the compiler for C++/CLI.

Comment: @DeadMG: Would you happen to have a link to Herb Sutter's details on this?

Comment: @DeadMG A pure C++ API can take a `com_ptr_t`, but a portable ABI can't, unless you demand a very specific representation for the smart pointer (which is why e.g. you can't use ATL `CComPtr<T>` in method signatures when writing COM components today, and have to take/return raw pointers). Granted, VC++ already lays out vtables in a very specific way for COM...

Comment: In my humble opinion, Yes this is really syntax abuse, maybe microsoft don't follow "keep it easy and clean", think about google, apple, ecc... if add some syntax to c++...

Answer (score 8):

"ref new" is a 2 token keyword.  It instructs the compiler to instantiate a windows runtime object and automatically manage the lifetime of the object (via the "^" operator).

Instantiating a windows runtime object causes an allocation, but it does not have to be on the heap.

Comment: Are the references dual mode values/refernces? When a reference goes out of scope, is it treated as if it was a CComPtr<T>? Can a ref class be instantiated on the stack like regular classes? Will WinRT/C++/CX support my old COM based code (interfaces as well as ATL based implementations)? Sorry for the burst of questions...

Comment: These aren't references - "ref new" is a language keyword, just like "new" is and "__gcnew" is.  As such, you can't instantiate them on the stack (can you instantiate a pointer on the stack?).  WinRT is a collection of APIs and a set of API patterns, so it's meaningless to say it supports COM based code.  C++/CX supports classic COM APIs, just like C++/CLI supports classic COM APIs.  You can use ATL in a C++/CX application, or you can use the new WRL template library (ComPTR<T>).

Comment: I have not seen any explicit calls to Release() in any example, so I'm guessing the compiler injects a call to Release() when the handle/pointer/reference (whatever they're called in CX) goes out of scope. Is that a correct guess?

Comment: That's correct - that's what I meant by "automatically manage the lifetime of the object"

Comment: From what I read on msdn, the ^ references contain two pointers, one to the object and one to the class definition, and their creation deletion behaves the same way as a C++11 shared_ptr would behave.
My hypothesis for the pointer to the class definition because WinRT objects were made to be easy to pass on to packages in other WinRT languages (C# and JavaScript). (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699870.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

ref in this case stands for reference counting. Classes using ref are WinRT component which have reference count machanisms out of the box.